# What does short-term dynamics mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm into an article wich describes "short-term dynamics" ( it's a ping pong ball falling with water from a height H.)
What does that term mean, I find nothing in internet...
Does it mean that we study the phenomenon during a time dt ?
Does it mean something else wich has implications (approximations or others..) ?

Regards